# YELP 1.0 JSON access with NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsjsonserialization, yelp

I was doing pretty good parsing YELP1 Json with NSJSONSerialization and accessing the data with NSDictionary. However, I figured inconsistencies in the response:

Some keys are surrounded with `"` , mostly the ones containing a `_`

Parts from the response:

```
(
        {
        address1 = "xxx";
        address2 = "";
        address3 = "";
        "avg_rating" = 5;
        city = "Chicago";
        country = USA;
        "country_code" = US;
```

Obtained from
 
`[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.recievedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

That's inconsistent to the documentation where no keys are in brackets.
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api

Aperently, the brackets indicate the '_' in the key value for some reason, not the type of the value. Brackets surround each key containing `_` , may the value be a *string* or a *int* or whatever.

Accessing fields such as avg_rating with

`[dict objectForKey:@"avg_rating"];`

fails with `NSInvalidArgumentException`

while `[dict objectForKey:@"country"];` would work.

Hence, I dont believe it's a NSDictionary / NSLog problem with the value returned, but a problem with the key submitted to the dict object. Or, maybe during the JSON parsing? But please, prove me wrong with piece of  working code... :)

Any ideas?
Thanks,
el

Edit: edited because question might now have been clear enough.
Edit2:
In fact, it was that a NSNumber is returned here. Got confused about these "" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parts from the response:

No. That's not part of the response. That's the description of the resulting `NSDictionary` which is ***NOT JSON.***

> `NSLog([dict objectForKey:@"avg_rating"]);` fails with `NSInvalidArgumentException`, while `NSLog([dict objectForKey:@"country"]);` would work.

Sure, because `NSLog()` ain't no magic. It expects a (format) string as its first argument, so if the object you feed it is an `NSString`, it will work fine (`country` is a string, I assume), but if you don't (`avg_rating` may be an `NSNumber`), then it won't (it will try to send the messages of `NSString` to the `NSNumber` instance, which obviously fails).

So understand the difference between JSON and the **description** of the `NSDictionary` generated from that JSON.